Query on reference to pointer in c++
Code:
int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::cout << int_array << " " << &int_array << " " << *(&int_array) << " " << **(&int_array) << " " << " " << *(int_array) << std::endl;   
   
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
  std::cout << i << " " << int_array[i] << " " << &int_array[i] << " " << *(&int_array[i]) <<  std::endl;
} 

Output:
0xd1a03ff9e0 0xd1a03ff9e0 0xd1a03ff9e0 1  1
0 1 0xd1a03ff9e0 1
1 2 0xd1a03ff9e4 2
2 3 0xd1a03ff9e8 3
3 4 0xd1a03ff9ec 4
4 5 0xd1a03ff9f0 5

Array Table:



Value
Address




1
0xd1a03ff9e0


2
0xd1a03ff9e4


3
0xd1a03ff9e8


4
0xd1a03ff9ec


5
0xd1a03ff9f0



int_array, &int_array, *(&int_array) all have output as 0xd1a03ff9e0.
Why is *(&int_array) equal to 0xd1a03ff9e0? As we can see, &int_array is 0xd1a03ff9e0, so shouldn't * to 0xd1a03ff9e0 be equal to 1?
What does int_array variable value and memory look like?

there is no reference in the code. In your code & is the addressof operator

Question for you: What is the type of &int_array?

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Does this answer your question? How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?

Address value of an array, and the address value of the first element of the array, have the same value.  They don't have the same type.

An array is not a pointer is not a single element.

Why is *(&int_array) equal to 0xd1a03ff9e0?

int_array is an array.
& is the address-of operator. &int_array is a pointer to array of 5 integers, ie int(*)[5]
* is the dereference operator. *(&int_array) is the original array.
When you pass an array to a function, it decays into a pointer to its first element, ie int*. The value of the pointer to the first element is the same as the value of the pointer to the whole array (but they are of different types!). Which takes us to ...

What does int_array variable value and memory look like?

An array is made up of consecutive elements:
[ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ][ 4 ]    // < - 5 consecutive integers in memory
  ^
  pointer to the array &int_array points here
  ^
  pointer to first element &int_array[0] points here

Again, you can see that the value of the pointer to int_array has the same value as the pointer to its first element, because an array starts with its first element in memory. There is nothing that comes before the first element.

There are many poor tutorials out there. I have seem some that claim int_array would be a pointer. But confusing an array with a pointer will lead to more confusion. Colloquially, we say int* p = new int[42]; is a pointer to an array. Colloquially this is ok, but confusing a pointer to an array with a pointer to a single element will lead the confusion in your question. Hence, an array is not a pointer is not a single element.

Too sleepy to proof read my own post. Upvoting you instead :-)

@Ted FWIW I was reading it when you deleted it. Looked ok so far (fairly far along through it). IMHO though it's very hard to do justice to questions like this without a long treatise on the subject. Short explanations just don't cut it for beginners and even a lot of "seniors" in my experience. The cryptic (arcane) syntax is hard enough without a lot of practice, but the biggest issue I believe is making people understand that an array is an object in its own right. Once people see that and acquire "chunking" skills through much practice, arrays and even so-called 2D arrays become far easier.
